# "Every regular function on an affine variety is polynomial" - generalisation to the case of a reducible variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$K$ is an algebraically-closed field, and for an affine variety $X$, $A(X) $ denotes the ring of polynomial functions on $X$.

What I would like to prove is the following:

"Let $X \subset \Bbb{A}^n(K)   $ be Zariski-closed, and $ f: X \rightarrow K   $ be regular; that is, for each $x \in X$ there's a neighbourhood $U_x $ containing $x$ and $g,h \in A(X)$, with $h$ nonzero on $U_x$ and $f = g/h$ on $U_x$. Then, $f \in A(X) $."

I've seen and understood a proof in the case where $X$ is irreducible, and I've also seen this thread - [Does a regular function on an affine variety lie in the coordinate ring?(Lemma 2.1, Joe Harris)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116966/does-a-regular-function-on-an-affine-variety-lie-in-the-coordinate-ringlemma-2) - where I agree with them that the proof in Harris fails at the penultimate line; but I didn't understand what was said in the answer (or indeed most of what was said in the question). What I'd like is if someone could give me a proof, or a link to a proof, of the general theorem; or could explain the answer in that other thread.

I've looked around the web for such a proof, but just can't find one. I'm halfway through a first course in algebraic geometry, so don't know about schemes, sheaves etc. but am fine with localisation and other undergrad (basic level grad?) commutative algebra. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241170/sheaf-of-germs-of-regular-functions-on-an-affine-variety

Comment: Yeah, that does it, thank you. I also found a proof in the notes "Algebraic Geometry" by J.S. Milne.